# Can't run sshd on a different port with command line (inside docker)

Tags: ssh, sshd, docker

I want to run sshd inside a ubuntu docker container on a different port than 22 (for a tunnel). I executed the commands from https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/. The first time i ran it I could connect to it ok from a different machine.  After I stopped and started the container I can't connect anymore to ssh (repeating restarting the container multiple times doesn't help).

All these tests I've done are from the same container.

I am using the following to start it:

```
$(which sshd) -Ddp  433
```

Which gives me the the following server started ok message:

```
root@86d80dc7a3d7:/home# $(which sshd) -Ddp  443                                                                                                                   
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014                                                                                                        
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker                                                                                                                   
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA                                                                                                                        
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA                                                                                                                            
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker                                                                                                                   
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA                                                                                                                        
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA                                                                                                                            
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker                                                                                                                   
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA                                                                                                                      
debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA                                                                                                                          
debug1: private host key: #3 type 4 ED25519                                                                                                                        
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'                                                                                                                             
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Ddp'                                                                                                                                       
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='443'                                                                                                                                        
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000                                                                                                                       
debug1: Bind to port 443 on 0.0.0.0.                                                                                                                               
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 443.                                                                                                                              
debug1: Bind to port 443 on ::.                                                                                                                                    
Server listening on :: port 443.
```

Everything seams good , I started a different terminal and tried to connect to it  ,but connecting to it gives me this connection refused error:

```
root@86d80dc7a3d7:/etc# ssh localhost -p 443                                                                                                                       
ssh: connect to host localhost port 443: Connection refused
```

It seams I can Telnet into the server via :

```
root@86d80dc7a3d7:/etc# telnet localhost 443                                                                                                                       
Trying ::1...                                                                                                                                                      
Connected to localhost.                                                                                                                                            
Escape character is '^]'.                                                                                                                                          
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1   
asda                                                                                                                                                               
Protocol mismatch.                                                                                                                                                 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I stopped the sshd server , started an echo server on the same port and I could telnet into it also from another mahine even.

I have also set it to allow any user to connect to it with "*PermitRootLogin yes*":

```
root@86d80dc7a3d7:/etc# sshd -T                                                                                                                                    
port 22                                                                                                                                                            
protocol 2                                                                                                                                                         
addressfamily any                                                                                                                                                  
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22                                                                                                                                           
listenaddress [::]:22                                                                                                                                              
usepam 1                                                                                                                                                           
serverkeybits 1024                                                                                                                                                 
logingracetime 120                                                                                                                                                 
keyregenerationinterval 3600                                                                                                                                       
x11displayoffset 10                                                                                                                                                
maxauthtries 6                                                                                                                                                     
maxsessions 10                                                                                                                                                     
clientaliveinterval 0 
clientalivecountmax 3                                                                                                                                              
permitrootlogin yes                                                                                                                                                
ignorerhosts yes                                                                                                                                                   
ignoreuserknownhosts no                                                                                                                                            
rhostsrsaauthentication no                                                                                                                                         
hostbasedauthentication no                                                                                                                                         
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly no                                                                                                                                 
rsaauthentication yes                                                                                                                                              
pubkeyauthentication yes                                                                                                                                           
kerberosauthentication no                                                                                                                                          
kerberosorlocalpasswd yes                                                                                                                                          
kerberosticketcleanup yes                                                                                                                                          
gssapiauthentication no                                                                                                                                            
gssapikeyexchange no                                                                                                                                               
gssapicleanupcredentials yes                                                                                                                                       
gssapistrictacceptorcheck yes                                                                                                                                      
gssapistorecredentialsonrekey no                                                                                                                                   
passwordauthentication yes                                                                                                                                         
kbdinteractiveauthentication no                                                                                                                                    
challengeresponseauthentication no                                                                                                                                 
printmotd no                                                                                                                                                       
printlastlog yes                                                                                                                                                   
x11forwarding yes                                                                                                                                                  
x11uselocalhost yes                                                                                                                                                
permittty yes                                                                                                                                                      
strictmodes yes                                                                                                                                                    
tcpkeepalive yes                                                                                                                                                   
permitemptypasswords no                                                                                                                                            
permituserenvironment no                                                                                                                                           
uselogin no 
compression delayed                                                                                                                                                
gatewayports no                                                                                                                                                    
usedns yes                                                                                                                                                         
allowtcpforwarding yes                                                                                                                                             
useprivilegeseparation yes                                                                                                                                         
pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid                                                                                                                                          
xauthlocation /usr/bin/xauth                                                                                                                                       
ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-c
tr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com                                                                                     
macs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hma
c-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.co
m,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com                                                                                  
versionaddendum                                                                                                                                                    
kexalgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecd
h-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org                                                                         
loglevel INFO                                                                                                                                                      
syslogfacility AUTH                                                                                                                                                
authorizedkeysfile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2                                                                                                      
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key                                                                                                                                  
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key                                                                                                                                  
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key                                                                                                                                
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key                                                                                                                              
acceptenv LANG                                                                                                                                                     
acceptenv LC_*                                                                                                                                                     
authenticationmethods                                                                                                                                              
subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server                                                                                                                        
maxstartups 10:30:100                                                                                                                                              
permittunnel no                                                                                                                                                    
ipqos lowdelay throughput                                                                                                                                          
rekeylimit 0 0                                                                                                                                                     
permitopen any
```

I can't find anything wrong with my config. Can someone

Comment: You should update your config to reflect your port settings.

Comment: Well that was weird. I restarted it again and it works now. The only problem now is that the servers stops as soon as the the client disconnects

Comment: if you run server in debug mode, it will work only for one connection. Remove `-d` flags and it will work for you (and also `-D`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-d` will run `sshd` in debug mode and it will accept only one connection and then it exists. Removing `-Dd` would make it working again

```
$(which sshd) -p  433
```

Additionally it is more clean to set port in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` using `Port` option, than using commandline option.